# input time from a form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have a code that allows the user to input time (i require only time and not date) from html form and it gets saved in database using php code

```
 <form>
  Select a time:
  <input type="time" name="usr_time">
</form>
```

But it does not support firefox browser, can anyone tell how to allow user to input time in am and pm format through a form

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using javascript or jquery
there are alot of libraries you can use easily
check out http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/
,,
or you can do this by adding more inputs like this

```
<input type="text" name="hours" placeholder="hours" /><br /><input type="text" name="minutes" placeholder="minutes" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jQuery [Timepicker](http://timepicker.co/) library to provide input contraints.

HTML

```
<link href="http://wvega.github.io/timepicker/resources/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.min.css" style="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
...
<form>
    <input type="text" class="timepicker" name="time"/>
</form>
...
<script src="http://wvega.github.io/timepicker/resources/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
```

JS

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('input.timepicker').timepicker();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

**[FIDDLE](http://timepicker.co/)**